# DOMPDF not rendering images that are secure links https but does for http

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am very new to larvel and have been looking all over but cant find an answer.

But I have a img links in our database that are https but once i generate the PDF i get a"img not found or unknown" when I change the images to http then they will display but then the page is not secure.

Not sure if that is a issue.

This is my first time looking into a backend issue like this so bare with me. and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SSL Certificate is not valid or if its self signed you need to allow that in order to make it work.

Something like this:

```
$pdf->getDomPDF()->setHttpContext(
    stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE,
            'verify_peer' => FALSE,
            'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
        ]
    ])
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked! been stuck for 3-4 days BUT now it loads the pdf very slow any idea why?

Comment: hello @Carter where did you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution After Trying many times
that make sure to install php BCMath module
:) It works for me :)

```
    chmod -R 777 /tmp
    sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
    
    systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```